# Ключи объекта - элементы массива

Tags: javascript, массивы, объекты

Возможно ли сделать объект такого вида? Выводится ошибка, что нельзя использовать квадратные скобки в ключах:

```
var base = {}, number = '12345', arr = ['type','class','addition'], one = 'add', two = 'me in', three = 'code';
base[number][arr[0]][arr[1]][arr[2]] = {"data": [one, two, three]};
```

Comment: Что здесь - что?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нет - это запрещено.

Когда вы используете `{}`, то вы создаете так называемый ассоицативный массив, который работает как `ключ -> значение`

В Вашем же случае, вы создаете ассоциативный массив без ключа и Javascript не будет знать, как найти этот элемент, который вы добавили туда.

Судя по тому, что вы хотите получить, вам надо сделать как-то так:

```
base = {};
base[number] = {};
base[number][arr[0]]={}
base[number][arr[0]][arr[1]]={}
base[number][arr[0]][arr[1]][arr[2]]={}
base[number][arr[0]][arr[1]][arr[2]] = {"data": [one, two, three]}
```

Результат будет:

```
{data: Array(3)}
```

Comment: Хорошо, с этим понятно. Но как тогда можно сделать такого вида объект? Мне нужна именно такая последовательность, чтобы использовать один объект, но с разными ключами?

Comment: @SoulHistory Я просто добавлю в свой ответ.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, то что нужно! А почему вы в конце строки не ставите ";"?

Comment: @SoulHistory Я проверял это и делал в Developers tools в Chrome и там они не обязательны. А так вы совершенно правы - ";" обязательно надо ставить.